# Edit SQL Server SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, packages

I ran the Export wizard to output some data to Excel, and I saved the package to run agan later. I now want to edit the SQL used to generate the Excel, but it is not clear how I do this.

The package is visible (in Stored Packages > MSDB) in SSIS, and I can execute it again, but I don't see a means to edit it. I also opened Business Intelligence Studio, through which I could see how to open a package stored as a file, but not how to open a package automatically stored in MSDB.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the package back to a file to be able to edit it.  There isn't a way to edit the files which are stored in the MSDB database.  If memory serves you should be able to right click on the package in Management Studio and export the package.  Then add it to the project and you can then edit it.